# C#-interactive gives ambiguous references when using two class libraries containing a common reference

Tags: c#-interactive

I am trying to use the C# interactive window inside VS 2015 Community.

I have two class libraries: CSVlib and FrameLib.  The former has a reference to the latter.  Here is the failing interactive code:

```
> #r "D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DataExplorer\CSVlib\bin\Debug\CSVlib.dll"
> using CSVlib;
> string fileName = @"D:\csvFiles\Players.csv";
> DataFrame frame = CSV.read(fileName);
> frame.colNames
List<string>(5) { "name", "city", "sex", "age", "weight" }
> ColumnData foo = frame["city"];
(1,1): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ColumnData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

ColumnData is a class defined in FrameLib and is returned by the DataFrame indexer.  It seems that class Frame is available via the reference in CSVlib, but not ColumnData.  I tried to reference Framelib explicitly, but cannot get that to work:

```
> #r "D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\DataExplorer\FrameLib\bin\Debug\FrameLib.dll"
> using FrameLib;
> DataFrame df = new DataFrame();
(1,1): error CS0104: 'DataFrame' is an ambiguous reference between 'CSVlib.DataFrame' and 'FrameLib.DataFrame'
(1,20): error CS0104: 'DataFrame' is an ambiguous reference between 'CSVlib.DataFrame' and 'FrameLib.DataFrame'
```

I can make a DataFrame with qualification:

```
> FrameLib.DataFrame df = new FrameLib.DataFrame();
```

But I am unable to get the CSV.read statement to work (the CSV.read returns a DataFrame):

```
FrameLib.DataFrame frame = CSV.read(fileName);
(1,28): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'CSVlib.DataFrame' to 'FrameLib.DataFrame'
```

This C# code, outside the interactive window (i.e. in another project) works fine:

```
 using CSVlib;
    using FrameLib;
    ...
    string fileName = @"D:\csvFiles\Players.csv";
    DataFrame frame = CSV.read(fileName);
    ColumnData foo = frame["city"];
```

How am I to use my two libraries to make the statements work in the interactive window?

Comment: Well it sounds like `CSV.read` returns a `CSVlib.DataFrame`, not a `FrameLib.DataFrame`... so use that: `CSVlib.DataFrame frame = CSV.read(fileName)`

Comment: That works, but it seems that the CSVlib.DataFrame is unaware of the indexer:

Comment: That suggestion works for that statement. However, the following code still fails:           > ColumnData foo = frame["city"];
                     variable not found: v01
                         + CSVlib.DataFrame.get_Item(string)
  It seems that CSVlib.DataFrame fails on the indexer in the IA window.  There is no variable v01 defined anywhere in my libraries. In any case: why are there two DataFrame types now defined? There should be only one, seemingly, if the code in the IA window and that in the solution are tp be equivalent.

Comment: Well does `CSVlib.DataFrame` *have* an indexer? Fundamentally, it sounds like there are two different types here that you're attempting to treat as one type. The fact that they have the same name doesn't change anything. It also sounds to me like C# interactive is getting in your way here more than helping - why not try to get it working in a normal C# environment first?

Comment: "In any case: why are there two DataFrame types now defined" - well it certainly *sounds* like you've declared a type called `DataFrame` in each library...

Comment: There is only one type DataFrame defined.  It is in FrameLib. If it were truly ambiguous, I would get a message in the C# code (outside the IA Window--see above). I suspect IA is constructing another type CSVlib.DataFrame because of the reference and usage inside CSVlib. The indexer for DataFrame is defined in FrameLib and returns a ColumnData (also defined in FrameLib).  All of this works fine outside IA window. I was hoping to use the IA as a "data explorer" (as in Python or "R"), where the REPL would be very useful. I don't think I can do it.

Comment: You might be able to investigate this by using `typeof(CSVlib.DataFrame).Assembly` and seeing where it thinks it's defined... as IA certainly seems to believe there is such a type.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake.  I had a debug/build misunderstanding.  In fact, there were indeed two types defined, left over from a debug build for "Any CPU" when I thought I was using the one from "x86". In fact, things work as they are supposed to. Thanks to John Skeet; sorry for the flub.